# Line break with JAVASCRIPT or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a way to make a linebreak in my product titles after a specific word.

> example: New Richmond Gold, Brown Strap

I would like to always add a break after Richmond

The title is css: h1.title
I got so far as to this: and its not working....

> var longWord = "h1.title".replace(/\Richmond/g, '.Richmond');

Comment: java or javascript? its not the same

Comment: This question deals with javascript and not java. So altered the title and the tags

Comment: I ended up fixing my problem with CSS.

h1.title:before {content: ''; float: right; width: 5em; height: 1em; }

Answer (score 0):

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title"),
     _title = title.innerText;
//title.innerText = _title.replace(/(richmond)/i, "$1\n")
title.innerText = _title.replace(/\b(\w+\s\w+)\s/i, "$1\n")
```

```html
<span id="title">New Richmond Gold, Brown Strap</span>
```